# Error lint al crear apk android studio

Tags: android

Me aparece este error al compilar una apk

> Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
>
> To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your
>   build script as follows:
>
> ```
> ...
> android {
>     lintOptions {
>         checkReleaseBuilds false
>         // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
>         // but continue the build even when errors are found:
>         abortOnError false
>     }
> ```

este es mi gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "doctorbateria.masterclean.speed.booster"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.4'

    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'

    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-js-rhino:1.3.1'

    compile 'com.github.pluscubed:recycler-fast-scroll:0.3.1@aar'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.john990:WaveView:16a10c1f9b'
    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularfillableloaders:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'


    compile 'com.mikepenz:actionitembadge:3.2.5@aar'

    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.11@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.jenzz:materialpreference:1.3'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-processes:1.0.9'
    compile project(':orm-library')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Algo anda mal, lo mejor es que veas en este dirección **[app module(el módulo de tu app)]/build/reports/lint-results-yourBuildName-fatal.html** y nos muestres el contenido.

Comment: Me salen errores referentes a faltas de traduccion , lo arreglare e intentare crear apk de nuevo.      (Overview
Correctness:Messages
8 error MissingTranslation: Incomplete translation
Disabled Checks (250)

DISMISS
Incomplete translation
../../src/main/res/values/strings.xml:30: "memory_used" is not translated in "ca" (Catalan), "da" (Danish), "de" (German))

Comment: Ahora al compilar me sale este error   Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 67789 into a non-jumbo instruction!
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 67789 into a non-jumbo instruction!, sources=[Unknown source file],

Comment: Cuando te piden alguna aclaración, debes editar la pregunta en lugar de usar los comentarios para poner código o más información.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es la verificación Lint:

> Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

si revisas el mensaje, dice en español:

> Lint encontró errores fatales al ensamblar y liberar el objetivo.
>
> Para continuar, corrija los problemas identificados por Lint o
>   modifique su secuencia de comandos de construcción de la siguiente
>   manera:

```
> ... android {
>     lintOptions {
>         checkReleaseBuilds false
>         // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
>         // but continue the build even when errors are found:
>         abortOnError false
>     }
```

Por lo tanto, dentro de tu archivo `app/build.gradle` agrega el bloque `lintOptions` dentro de `android` :

```
android {

    ...
    ...
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bien, por lo que veo, el límite de 64k te está afectando, edita tu Module Gradle para que puedas eliminar esta falla de esta manera:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Activando el multidex, te permitirá eliminar el problema de límite de 64K.